# Настройка элемента в CSS через aria-label?

Tags: css

В CSS всегда элемент находят через классы.

```
.contentSpacing.main-entityHeader-container {
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Но возможно ли как то настраивать элемент в CSS через aria-label? Если да, то как?

Comment: Используйте квадратные скобки. ```[aria-label=test] { ... }```

Comment: @OliverPatterson, что то не работает... В CSS так и писать? 

`[aria-label=тест] {margin-left: 10px;}` ?

Comment: Да, должно работать. Можете предоставить кусочек html кода, где используется этот aria-label?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, Разобрался. Вы забыли поставить кавычки) `[aria-label="test"] { ... }`

Comment: Вот и отлично))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть отличная "справка" по селекторам атрибутов. Ссылочка: [Селекторы атрибутов | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

- [attr]  Обозначает элемент с атрибутом по имени attr.
- [attr=value]  Обозначает элемент с именем атрибута attr и значением в точности совпадающим с value.
- [attr~=value]  Обозначает элемент с именем атрибута attr значением которого является набор слов разделённых пробелами, одно из которых в точности равно value
- [attr|=value]  Обозначает элемент с именем атрибута attr. Его значение при этом может быть или в точности равно "value" или может начинаться с "value" со сразу же следующим "-" (U+002D). Это может быть использовано когда язык описывается с подходом.
- [attr^=value]  Обозначает элемент с именем атрибута attr значение которого начинается с "value"
- [attr$=value]  Обозначает элемент с именем атрибута attr чьё значение заканчивается на "value"
- [attr*=value]  Обозначает элемент с именем атрибута attr чьё значение содержит по крайней мере одно вхождение строки "value" как подстроки.